# Are the return values from class get methods garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, performance, memory-management, garbage-collection

Let's say I have a class with a method `calculatePrice` that returns a value.  It also has another method which uses `calculatePrice`:

```js
class SodaCan {

  constructor(id, otherArgs) { 
    this.id = id
    // more constructor logic
  }

  calculatePrice() {
    // do some calculations for tax, recycling, whatever
    return price;
  }

  savePriceToDb() {
    const price = this.calculatePrice();
    database.save(this.id, { price });
  }

}

// in the global scope:
const coke = window.coke = new SodaCan('someId', 1.19)
coke.savePriceToDb();
```

Once `savePriceToDb` has finished execution, there are no more references to `price`, so my assumption is that `price` gets garbage collected.  However, `coke.id` does not get garbage collected, as it is a property of `coke`, which is available in the global scope. If this is incorrect, please let me know!

Now let's say we change `calculatePrice` to a get method, say `get price`:

```js
class SodaCan {

  constructor(id, otherArgs) { 
    this.id = id
    // more constructor logic
  }

  get price() {
    // do some calculations for tax, recycling, whatever
    return price;
  }

  savePriceToDb() {
    const price = this.price;
    database.save(this.id, { price });
  }

}

// in the global scope:
const coke = window.coke = new SodaCan('someId', 1.19)
coke.savePriceToDb();
```

(Granted the `savePriceToDb` function doesn't really need to say `const price = this.price`, as it could just call `database.save(this.id, { price: this.price })`)

With the `get` syntax, the result of `this.price` is attached to the instance.  Since `coke` is available in the global scope, `coke.price` would still have references to it, and would *not* get garbage collected.  Is that correct?

If my assumptions are correct, is this a disadvantage of using a `get` method on a class, in terms of memory management?  Please let me know if I'm not understanding something here, or if my assumptions are incorrect.

Comment: Garbage collection is fine using get or not using get, it's no different.  Your only real GC problem is sticking a reference to window in the first place.

Comment: I mean in my real code I'm not attaching it to `window` or `global`, it was more of an example to illustrate the question.  In the real code, I may have hundreds or thousands of `SodaCan`s in memory at a given moment and I'm trying to practice good memory management within a given `SodaCan` to optimize many concurrent instances.  Can you elaborate on how "it's no different"?

Comment: Your fine creating lots of `SodCan`s, everything will GC, there is no special memory management you need here.  Both your get & your calculatePrice both return a number type, there is nothing different here.  Not sure how I can elaborate anymore.

Comment: It depends on the nature of what is encompassed by the comment `// do some calculations for tax, recycling, whatever`. If you are storing information in the object instance, you may be increasing the memory usage, but the *caller*, by virtue of using a property rather than a method call, is not specifically creating any more or less memory overhead. Note, however, that as a developer, if I'm getting the value of a property, I expect it to take very little time and not have any side effects (other property values changing, etc.), whereas when I call a method, I do expect it may take more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With the get syntax, the result of `this.price` is attached to the instance.

No it isn't. The getter just makes it look like the value is a property, but it isn't really. Every time you read `this.price` it calls the getter function and returns the value, just like the `calculatePrice()` method. The value is not attached anywhere.

So if the caller doesn't save the price anywhere, it will become garbage.

Comment: Straight and to the point.  Thanks for clearing up my misconception and answering the question in the process.